# Defining proper transfer function from measuring step using Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm hitting a bump with Octave.
Im working on a motor/system. I put amps in and speed comes out. I gave it a step by applying 1A and the motor started running. I logged its speed and between 0 and 2 seconds the response is a bit to well described by y described in the code below. Now its fairly easy to describe this system as a first order system. When plotting y and stepping H_sys1th they look somewhat the same. Hoping to get better results i ask octave to do a step response on H_sysd but the result looks nothing like it. What am i doing wrong? My goal is to have a transfer function in the S domain representing y as close as possible.

```
% Import the Control package
pkg load control

% function written as Y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
% edit below values:
a = 20;
b = -90;
c = 200;
d = -10;
dt = 0.001; % sample frequency of controller (1Khz) = 0.001
t_sim = 2; % step response length

% Transfer function Plant:
t = 0 : dt : t_sim;     % Time Vector [s]
y = a*t.^3 + b*t.^2 + c*t + d;
H_sys = tf([0, d, c, 2*b, 6*a],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
H_sysd = c2d(H_sys, 0.001);

% First order transfer funciton
K = 160;
T = 0.9;
E = 1;
H_sys1th = tf ([K], [T, E])

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(t, y)
title('Function System')

subplot(1,2,2)
step(H_sysd, 'b', H_sys1th, 'r', t)
title('Step Transfer Function System')
```

[image: Image 1, Left Y, right red = first order TF, blue = 3th order TF]

Image 1, Left Y, right red = first order TF, blue = 3th order TF

Comment: Can you append the plot images you're currently getting?

Comment: Shure Thing, the scale of the vertical axis is not the same. My problem is with the sape of the blue line on the right side.

Comment: just verifying that I got the same output using Matlab, so it appears that the octave functions are performing as expected.